# Get URL ID from Angular for PHP query

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I am currently building my first angular app and I have got to a stage which has left me stumped for a few days now.

I have it where I go to a URL like this:
index.php#!/report-listing/56

The ID changes dependent on what report you have clicked on. I need to figure out a way I can get this ID for my PHP so I can use it in mySQL so I can pull out the correct details for this ID.

Any help be appreciated.

So at the moment this is how I am creating the link in PHP:

```
<a class="btn bg-green" href="#!/report-listing/<?php echo $row['tripreportid'];?>"></span>Manage</a>
```

This is my controller.js:

```
function ReportListingsCtrl($scope, $http, $timeout,$routeParams) {$scope.id=$routeParams.reportId;}
```

This is my App.js:

```
    when('/report-listing/:reportId', {
      templateUrl: 'pages/report-listing.php',
      controller: ReportListingsCtrl,
      activetab: 'report-listing'
    }).
```

How on the new page can I retrieve this ID without using PHP as I have been advised ths is not the way to do it?

Comment: There is no need to get it via PHP, make it via Angular and send $http request to your PHP API or script. Otherwise front-end part will become more or less useless.

Comment: Can you update the question with some sample code to explain your problem?

Comment: I have updated it to have the code and expanded he question.

Comment: Are you not getting it from `$routeParams.reportId` as shown in your controller? Question is very confusing since there wouldn't be any php in your angular templates